# Chain recurrent set is the set of fixed points?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

**Definition:**
Given $x,$ $y\in X$ and $\alpha>0,$ $x$ is $\alpha$ -related to $y$ (written $x\stackrel{\alpha}{\sim} y$ ) if there are $\alpha$ -pseudo-orbits of $f$ such that $x_{0}=x,$ $x_{1},$ $\cdots,$ $x_{k}=y$ and $y_{0}=y,$ $y_{1},$ $\cdots,$ $y_{l}=x$ . If $x\stackrel{\alpha}{\sim} y$ for every $\alpha>0$ , then $x$ is related to $y$ (written $x\sim y$ ). The chain recurrent set of $f,$ $R$ is $\{x\in X:x\sim x\}$.

**My question:** If $x\sim x$, then for each $\alpha>0$ there exists a sequence of points $x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_k=x$ such that $d(f(x_i),x_{i+1})<\alpha.$ Hence, $d(f(x),x)<\alpha$. Since, $\alpha>0$ was arbitrary we have $d(f(x),x)=0.$ Thus, $f(x)=x.$ So isn't the chain recurrent set of $f$ just the set of fixed points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote out the meaning of $x \sim x$ under the heading of "My question", you made two mistakes which, if fixed, should clear this up.

First, the sequence of points should be written $x=x_0,x_1,...,x_k=x$ (you left out the initial $x=x_0$).

Second, the distance condition is that $d(f(x_i),x_{i+1}) < \alpha$ for each $i=0,...,k-1$ (you left out the quantifier "for each...").

So we have
$$d(f(x),x_1) = d(f(x_0),x_1) < \alpha
$$
and so on as $i$ increases, up to
$$d(f(x_{k-1}),x) = d(f(x_{k-1}),x_k) < \alpha
$$
but none of this implies $d(f(x),x) < \alpha$.

Comment: But $x_i =x$ for each $i=0,\cdots,k-1.$  Or wait, does the definition only mean that the first and last point are $x?$

Comment: That's right, a notation like $x=x_0,x_1,...,x_{k-1},x_k=x$ means that $x=x_0$ and that $x_k=x$, but it does not say anything about $x$ equalling any of the in-between values $x_1$,...,$x_{k-1}$. You've perhaps encountered notation like that before, for instance in a discussion of Riemann sums in a Calculus textbook.

Comment: I was confused because $,$ usually means "and." Thanks for the clarification.